# gzip or deflate files can it be merged together? for api

Tags: php, encoding, compression, gzip, deflate

i have api that let you get one or more files content in one request and i have them as deflate/gzip and normal text, for now im using normal text, but was wondering if i can merge deflate files and sent back on the request as i do for normal, will it still work?

i tried some testing, but only one file content shows in browser and other dont, but i saw there is some example of sending multiple gzip files on fly as zip file. so i wanted to know if its possible and if yes, then how can i do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gzip only supports a single file internally. It's not a container format, just a straight deflation. There's no provision to maintain a directory of where one file ends and another starts, let along the file metadata (filename, creation date, size, etc...)

You can use .tar to glom multiple files together, and then gzip the .tar file. Or use zip to wrap multiple files (of any type) into a single .zip file. Since you say you'd be zipping .gz'd files, I'd suggest just using zip as a container, with compression disabled. The few bytes you'd save by recompressing the .gz files won't be worth the CPU overhead to do the extra compression run.

Comment: after using zip, can i display that multiple files as text on browser, just like we sent back the gzip files (javascript, css, text, json...) to browser and it shows fine.. would it will do same for zip files? also what about deflate, or defalte and gzip are same way...

Comment: Umm... no. Compressed files are basically binary garbage as far as humans legibility is concerned.

Comment: isnt there a way to do it? cause i wanted to have json request stored and when user request for it, then just sent them from gz files, not reading one file at a time, but two or three json gz files and senting them back the response..  do i really have to uncompress them and then recompress togather?

Comment: Yes. HTTP doesn't really handle multiple files in a single request nicely, and gzip doesn't support multiple files in a single .gz, so you have to use other tools like tar as well, or use something like zip, which is kinda tar+gzip-in-one.